# Getting manifest error after run snapshot.jar file in terminal ....which manifest i should add?

Tags: java, apache-poi

i add dependency but i am getting exception

dom4j
poi
poi-ooxml
poi-ooxml-schemas
xmlbean

this is my code

```
        File resourceFile = new File("chargeholdermapping.xlsx");   
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(resourceFile);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row;
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            String originalValues = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            String showingValues = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            pstm = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.setString(1, originalValues);
            pstm.setString(2, showingValues);
            pstm.execute();
            System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
        }
```

Comment: i am getting this errorException in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OLE2NotOfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the OLE2 Format. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OOXML (Office Open XML) Documents. You need to call a

Comment: Edit your question to include the stack trace rather than posting it as a comment - that's not what comments are for

Comment: If you're not sure what kind of file you have (as the error tells you), why not switch to `WorkbookFactory` and let Apache POI figure it out for you?

Comment: all working good but at the time of create snapshot.jar file and that jar file i ran in terminal its give manifest error ....which manifest i should add......i already add so many time different different but no one is working,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Add Dependencies
**POM.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: it is runnning good ,,,,but when i create a snapshot.jar file it is not working .........saying that u need to add manifest ..........i add many manifest but gives error noClassFound error .........UserModel.Row classNotFound error